transparent object vs world background
I have an object, say object 1. it is a semi transparent object, with another object inside, say object 2. Now I introduced a world background so it renders nice but when i do this the backgorund interferes with my transparent object1. so i have to make object1 less transparent but this time object 2 inside becomes less visible. how can i for example make objects not affected by background or what else might you suggest for this situation?
